# Unable to send email with Itemattachment having more than 5 Internetmessageheaders

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Im trying to send the email with Itemattachment from shared mailbox to another email address.
While sending I'm getting the below error message. Please help.
Code: InvalidInternetMessageHeaderCollection
Message: Maximum number of headers in one message should be less than or equal to 5.

graphClient.Users[MailboxAddress.MailBoxSMTPAddress].MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages.Request().Filter("isRead ne true").Top(10).Expand("attachments");

```
        var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await Toptenmessagesquery4.GetAsync());
        var messages = task.Result;
        foreach (var message in messages)
            try
            {
                {
                    foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
                    {
                        if (attachment.ODataType == "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment")
                        {

                            var attachmentRequest = graphClient.Users[MailboxAddress.MailBoxSMTPAddress].MailFolders["Inbox"].Messages[message.Id]
                                          .Attachments[attachment.Id].Request().Expand("microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item").GetAsync();
                            var itemAttachment = (ItemAttachment)attachmentRequest.Result;
                            /*var itemMessage = (Message)itemAttachment.Item;*/  //get attached message
                            MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();
                            attachments.Add(new ItemAttachment
                            {
                                ODataType = "#microsoft.graph.itemAttachment",
                                ContentType =itemAttachment.ContentType,
                                Item = itemAttachment.Item,                                 
                                IsInline=itemAttachment.IsInline,
                                Id=itemAttachment.Id,
                                Name=itemAttachment.Name,
                                Size=itemAttachment.Size
                               
                            });
                            var email = new Message
                            {
                                Subject = message.Subject,
                                Body = message.Body,
                             
                                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                                {
                                    new Recipient
                                    {
                                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                                        {
                                            Address = "xyz@xyz.com"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                Attachments = attachments,
                              
                            };
                            graphClient
                      .Users["abc@abc.com"]
                      .SendMail(email, false)
                       .Request()
                       .PostAsync().Wait();
                             
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception("Error in send email:", ex);
            }
```